# ag-dnd-ghost element is missing in release application

Tags: typescript, ag-grid-angular

Am new to ag-grid, i have installed 22.1.1 version of ag-grid in my project
I am using angular 5 .
Column reorder is working in my local system
But when i release those changes using Azure pipeline it does not work and i cant see ag-dnd-ghost element when trying to drag the column. Nothing happens when trying to move the column.

I tried to add Z-index to ag-dnd-ghost in my styles
[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORpgt.png)

Can someone help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello Navyasri, from your post it's not very what's going on. It might be that the code deployed on your azure system is different than your localhost. Perhaps sharing a link to the code and to the deployed staging/production application will help you get more help. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Amit, the deployed code and local is same since other all functionalities like filter, sorting, resizse column everything works fine for ag-grid in my deployed project. I could not share the application link since it will not be accessed.